# Check if the value of text box is inside the array

Tags: arrays, vb6

below is my array and code to check if the data in textbox is inside of the array. the problem is when i run the program the value of array is always " " or no data found.. what's wrong with my code? please help me.. thank you.

```
        a = Split((a), vbTab)
    devices = Array("iPhone5", "iPhone4", "iPhone3", "iPad", "iPod", "iPhone4s", "iPhone3G", "iPhone3gs", "gt-s5360", "gt-i9505", "n7100", "gt-n7100", "i9300", "gt-i9300", "gt-p3100", "s5300", "gt-s5300", "gt-s7562", _
            "gt-i8190", "s100", "p5100", "gt-p5100", "gt-s6102", "gt-i9100", "gt-p3110", "gt-p6200", "n8000", "gt-n8000", "gt-i9082", "sm-t210", "gt-n7105", "n7000", "gt-n7000", "gt-n5100", "GT-S5570", "GT-S5830i", _
            "GT-S5830", "GT-I8262", "GT-P1000", "Nexus 7", "GT-I8160", "H120", "ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 918N", "HuaweiG510-0200", "MyPhone A919 Duo", "MyPhone A848i Duo", "C6603", "ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 4030E", "LG-E400", _
            "GT-P6800", "ICE 350e", "GT-I9070", "ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 5021E", "Cherry w500", "GT-I8150", "LT22i", "Spark TV", "I9500", "GT-I9500", "Burst S280", "W120", "GT-P7500", "MyPhone A888 Duo", "GT-S5301", "Thunder S220", "GT-S7500", _
            "GT-I8552", "SM-T211", "GT-S5282", "A818 Duo", "LT26i", "GT-S6802", "GT-S5570I", "HuaweiY210-0100", "LT26w", "HTC One", "ST23i", "ST27i", "SHW-M250S", "Cruize W280", "Titan TV S320", "B1-A71", "GT-I9152", "W110", "7038", _
            "LT18i", "GT-P3113", "GT-I9000", "Cherry Sonic", "GT-S5670", "SHW-M110S", "ST26i", "SonyEricssonMT25i", "Excite_352g", "LT25i", "Lenovo A390_ROW", "ST25i", "LG-E612", "GT-I9003")
    urls = Array("youtube.com", "ytimg.com", "DoubleClick.net", "google.com", "fbcdn.net", "google -analytics.com", "yimg.com", "googlesyndication.com", "facebook.com", "gstatic.com", "mywebacceleration.com", "yahoo.com", "scorecardresearch.com", _
            "google.com.ph", "adnxs.com", "redtubefiles.com", "rubiconproject.com", "wattpad.net", "www.com", "youjizz.com", "bing.net", "akamaihd.net", "xvideos.com", "tumblr.com", "twitter.com", "yieldmanager.com", "sharethis.com", "wikimedia.org", _
            "y8.com", "sulitstatic.com", "globe.com.ph", "googleapis.com", "tagstat.com", "quantserve.com", "addthis.com", "blogspot.com", "king.com", "cloudfront.net", "ayosdito.com", "ask.com", "openx.net", "bigspeedpro.com", "gravatar.com", _
            "amasvc.com", "bing.com", "cdn.com", "yldmgrimg.net", "cedexis.com")



For intX = 0 To UBound(a)
        If Text11.Text = "" Then
          a(intX) = UCase(a(intX))
            Text11.Text = a(intX)
        ElseIf Text12.Text = "" Then
          a(intX) = UCase(a(intX))
            Text12.Text = a(intX)
            If Len(Text12.Text) <= 17 Then
                Text12.Text = ""
            Else
                b = Split(Text12.Text, "/")
                For i = 0 To UBound(b)
                    Text12.Text = b(2)
                Next
                 Text12 = InStr(Text12, urls)
                    If Text12 = UCase(urls) Then
                        Text22 = Text12
                        Text25 = count + 1
                    Else
                        Text26 = Text12
                        Text27 = othercount + 1
                    End If
            End If
```

Comment: when i change the urls into urls().. i got an error "Expected Array".. what should i do? this is my first time to use array in vb6.. someone please help me.. thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to have the problem in it with the exception of the first line. Do you dimension the variable `a` somewhere? It appears you are trying to split a string, and reassign it to the same variable. Add an `Option Explicit` statement as the very first line in your code, dimension a string array variable and try assigning `Split(a, vbTab)` to that.

Comment: yes, i already mention the variable a and parse it using split, i also have option explicit at the top of my codes. my only problem is the array..

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the smallest complete amount of code which will compile, and reproduce your bug. Otherwise we are reliant on guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ForEach to make it more effective.
Or use this function... :)

```
Public Function IsContained(theArray() As Variant, strSearchPharse As String, Optional IsMatch As Boolean = False, Optional IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
If Not UBound(theArray)  0 Then End
Dim strExploded As String
Dim gsChache As Boolean
gsChache = False 'set the default value
'Checking for every array thing
    For Each strExploded In theArray
    If IsMatch And Not (Len(strSearchPharse) = Len(strExploded)) Then 'if its matchable...
            If IsCaseSensitive And strExploded = strSearchPharse Then gsChache = True
            If Not IsCaseSensitive And LCase(strExploded) = LCase(strSearchPharse) Then gsChache = True
    ElseIf Not IsMatch And Not IsCaseSensitive Then 'if its not matchable, and not case sensitive
        If InStr(0, LCase(strExploded), LCase(strSearchPharse)) >= 1 Then gsChache = True
    Else 'if its not matchable, and Case Sensitive
        If InStr(0, strExploded, strSearchPharse) >= 1 Then gsChache = True
    End If
    DoEvents
    Next strExploded

IsContained = gsChache 'finish
End Function
```

How to use it?
theArray is for array variable, strSearchPharse is the text you want to search (like keyword, e.g. apple or youtube), then isMatch is is the text you want to search is need to exactly same (not case sensitive, buat it will if you enable it.), IsCaseSensitive is the text you need to search on is need to case sensitive or not.
the default setting is, Not Matchable, and Case Sensitiveable.

Sample:

```
XYZ = Array("Satu", "Dua", "Tiga", "Empat", "Lima", "Enam", "Tujuh", "Delapan", "Sembilan", "Sepuluh")
If IsContained(XYZ, "o", , False) Then
    MsgBox "The Array contains o alphabet."
Else
    MsgBox "The Array have no o alphabet."
End If
```

The result will show "The Array contains o alphabet." MsgBox... :)

Comment: hi @Gunawan Christianto.. can you please give me a running code about array?